# Converting if to ternary not working after first execution

Tags: vimrc

I have two functions, one using an `if` statement and one using (or trying to use) a ternary expression:

```
nnoremap <expr> Z Toggle1()
func Toggle1 ()
    if g:colors_name == "OceanicNext"
        return ":colorscheme TextMate^M"
    else
        return ":colorscheme OceanicNext^M"
endfunc

nnoremap <expr> Q Toggle2()
func Toggle2 ()
    echom g:colors_name
    let cs = "TextMate" ? (g:colors_name == "OceanicNext") : "OceanicNext"
    let cmd_string = printf(":colorscheme %s^M", cs)
    return cmd_string
endfunc
```

The first one works, but the second one only 'works' the first time I run it. What's the difference between the two, and what am I doing wrong in the second one?

Comment: The ternary operator is borrowed from C. It's syntax `condition ? value1 : value2`

Comment: @Matt -- sure, but that's what I have here, right?

Comment: Just look at your code: what stands before "question" and what after it?

Comment: @Matt d'oh! I see, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Matt based on your other answers, I ended up using this for the mapping: `nnoremap <expr> CC g:colors_name == "oceanicnext" ? ":colorscheme textmate^M" : ":colorscheme oceanicnext^M"`